# how to read text from notepad and save it to excel file in UiPath

Tags: rpa, uipath

Input from notepad:
Name : Vineet
Id : 123
City : Nod
Name : XYZ
Id : 987
City : ABC

Output I want:
Name     Id    City
Vineet   123   Nod
XYZ      987   ABC

Output I 'am getting:
Name  Vineet
Id    123
City  Nod
Name  XYZ
Id    987
City  ABC

How solve this issue in Uipath ?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you have, exactly what you want and what you've done so far?  Otherwise you could just use an activity to read the text file entirely, then manipulate the text in memory

Comment: Steps are as per : Read text file  - Generate Data table - Write Range - Run

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell by how your question has formatted but the comment states you want to create a DataTable.
I'm also assuming the data is written exactly as it appears in the question:
"Name : Vineet Id : 123 City : Nod Name : XYZ Id : 987 City : ABC"

1. Read Text File. Output Result will be a string.
   [image]
2. Build Data Table - Output is DataTable
   [image]

Set the Headers to your requirements.

3. Then do some formatting so Split into an Array

   formatNotepad = notepadOutput.Replace(" :", ":")

   personnelList = Split(formatNotepad, "Name:")
4. Use a For Each (set Argument type to String)
   Worth adding a IsNullOrEmpty step as the first row will be blank due to how the Split was done at Step 3.

Then use a Multi Assign to split the "Item" and obtain the details by getting the Index of the Array.

Then use the "Add Data Row" Activity

[image]

5. Write Range using the DataTable

[image]